# Which nuget package contains MediaTypeNames?

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-2.2

I have two projects:

- an ASP.NET Core 2.2 project (`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`), which references the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage
- a supporting "utils" project (`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`), which references various nuget packages that I need in that project (I can't just reference the metapackage as it's not a web project type)

In the utils project I need to reference `MediaTypeNames.Application.Json`. I discovered it is in the `System.Net.Mime` namespace, which is in the `System.Net.Mail` assembly.

But that is in a beta [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/system.net.mail), which was surprising. Also, the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` metapackage [doesn't reference it](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App), which was also surprising and confusing.

So which nuget package should I reference in my utils project, so I can use `MediaTypeNames.Application.Json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you linked to has a description that says "This is an untested port of System.Net.Mail" and if you look at the owner, it's not Microsoft. This is certainly not an official package.

Looking at [the docs for `MediaTypeNames.Application.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mime.mediatypenames.application.json?view=netstandard-2.1&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.8), it says it's available for netcoreapp2.1 and netcoreapp2.2 and the previews of netcoreapp3.0 and netstandard2.1. It doesn't say anything about a pacakge being available for other TFMs.

Comment: Thanks. So how do I access it in a utils project that is declared with `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` and `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`?

Comment: you can't while targeting netstandard2.0

Comment: Okay now I understand. Thanks.